# Align smaller triangle to the center of a larger triangle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, alignment

I am trying to create an equilateral triangle with a smaller equilateral triangle cut directly from it's center, like a stencil. I have made the triangle and used the `Path Selection Tool` to copy it and use it as a subtraction. The second triangle is now 50% smaller:

[image: Equilateral triangle stencil]

How can I align the smaller triangle to the exact center of the larger one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is one of those cases where its about 100 times faster to do this in *Illustrator*. But given that you must use Photoshop for this here is how you find  center of mass of the triangle, which is what your after:

1. Draw the triangle
2. Select one edge with the *Direct Selection Tool* (White arrow). There will be no apparent feedback that you have succeeded.
3. Copy the segment, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
4. Paste copied segment, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
5. Enter *Free Transform*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

   - Rotate 90 degrees
6. Repeat from step 2 for another edge.

[image: Center]

**Image 1:** Triangle and its center of mass.

Where the edges cross is where your triangle has its center of mass.

7. Scale a copy of all paths to 50% and align centers.

Now I really recommend you do this in *Illustrator*  instead, if you have it. Its infinitely easier to be accurate. You can always paste the shape into *Photoshop*.

[image: Result]

**Image 2**: Result

Comment: "Select one edge..." - I am using the tool you suggested and clicking on the edge, but it does not appear to be selected. What steps would I do to achieve the result in _Illustrator_?

Comment: @Deryllium It will not highlight in any meaningful way. It can be still selected. You will just have to know this.

Comment: Scale a copy of all paths to 50% and align centers. Illustrator would snap at intersection but PS will not

Answer (score 0):

A better idea requiring much less effort is to select the shape tool, and choose custom shape. Within the options settings for the shape tool, select for it to be represented as a path. Right click on the canvas, and find the triangle depicted below. It is perfectly aligned to the center with the cut-out you requested. Stroke and or fill to your liking in paths dialog located behind the layers display.

[image]